# Email input in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In HTML5 we have something like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email">
```

In Spring MVC I have a form input with model path just like this:

```
 <form:input path="email" cssClass="form-control" id="firstname" />
```

And it is treated as text input. Is it possible to change type of the input to email?

Comment: Well, the JavaDoc on [`<form:input>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form-tld.html#spring-form.tld.input) states: "Renders an HTML 'input' tag with type 'text' using the bound value.". Why don't you use the html tag directly? It might require some more work but should give you more flexibility if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use HTML5 types](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-mvc-jsp-form-tags-example) (right at the bottom there) by providing them in the `type` attribute (the default being "text") e.g.

`<form:input type="email" path="email" cssClass="form-control" id="firstname" />`